# SQL Server : capture views using Profiler

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-profiler

I have a SQL Server with dozen of databases and thousands of objects. I need to run a scenario from my client side and check what views were used in the process. They might be called from a stored procedure or used directly.

I tried the next events without success:

- SP: Starting/Completed
- SP: StmtStarting/StmtCompleted

It is capturing triggers, stored procedures, functions but not views.

Please advise.

Comment: This is because a view is like a table. It isn't a function or a procedure. You don't execute a view, you execute a select statement which might reference a view. You will have to parse the code in your procedures and such to know what views are being used. Or check out sys.depends.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the `SQL:StmtCompleted` Event and search the `TextData` column for the name of your view.